# How to switch from Ubuntu gnome to Xubuntu

Tags: gnome, xubuntu

I am currently using ubuntu GNOME as desktop environment and my computer is dual-booting between Ubuntu and and windows. I want to switch from GNOME to Xubuntu without losing any of my data. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install package *xubuntu-desktop*:

`sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`

reboot and choose Xubuntu session in the login screen. The Ubuntu Gnome related stuff is still installed, so you always can switch to Gnome back if you change your mind.

However, if you want to wipe-out Ubuntu Gnome for good (believe me, there is no reason to do so), then I would recommend to make backup of your data and then clean install of Xubuntu.